Manhwa with a female lead who is a shape shifter with ice powers, the male lead has fire powers
There is a female lead who is a shape shifter with ice powers. She had a younger sibling. She lives in a forest. There is male lead with fire powers. The female lead saves her little sister and that how they meet.

Is this Frozen Wolf, Fire Dragon...?

Eve was once a human woman who loved to read romance novels. But after being reincarnated as an ice magic-wielding wolf hybreed in one of her favorite stories, Eve runs into a dragon hybreed named Rahel who will kill her in the future and fall in love with her little brother, Sion. Now, Eve thinks her only hope of survival is to save enough money to move to the human world. But as Rahel grows more attached to her, Eve has no idea if she'll cool Rahel's fiery nature or burn in a blazing inferno!


A Korean woman is reborn in the world of a novel she'd read as Eve, the daughter of an ice sorcerer and a 'wolf hybreed.' Eve has ice powers, looks like a human girl with wolf ears, and lives in a house in a snowy forest with her younger brother, Sion.
One day, she finds a girl lying unconscious in the snow and brings her back to her house to help her recover. Since she retains memories of the novel's plot, Eve realises that this girl is Rahel Ramier, the younger sister of Noelier, the Southern Chief and a 'dragon hybreed' with fire powers.
Noelier has been searching for Rahel for days and meets Eve in the forest in chapter 7, initially thinking that she kidnapped Rahel. Rahel then rushes to Eve's defence, and Noelier realises that Eve was actually taking care of her.
You can read the full manhwa at Tapas.
